# What is the exact time taken by Application insight to Log the error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I am using Application insight for Logging. Some times it logs the error in fraction of second & some time it takes upto 1 minute. some time more then that

I am using

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = true;
```

So i am unable to figure out, what is the process at the backed. Is it some job running for each minute?

Comment: Hope [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51954913/7073340) will put some light for your question

Comment: Thanks, this helped to understand the back end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the developer mode is set to true, the telemetry data would be sent asap(Otherwise, it will buffer telemetry data and send it in batches).

And regarding it will take some time to shown in azure portal, I think the data would be processed again then be shown on portal. I have submitted an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/964) to track this.

However, the quickest way to see the telemetry data is using Visual Studio output window. It can show the telemetry data asap:
[image]

And if it's a web application, you can also use `Application Insights Search` button in visual studio:
[image]

View all the telemetry datas:
[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-live-stream LiveStream feature can help to see data within seconds, but this data is not persisted.